# How to make key completely dependent on the other key on firebase databse?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a firebase realtime database to store the data. The data format looks like this:-

```
users: {
   user1: // user details
   user2: // user details
 }
 data : {
    user1: // user data
    user2: // user data
 }
```

What is want to do is when I delete the user details the user data should automatically be deleted.
Can we define this dependency like this, if yes how?

Answer (score 2):

Using Cloud Functions you can delete an user data everytime an user detail record has been deleted. The code for your Cloud Function should look something like this:

```
exports.deleteData = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')
.onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
  return snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('data').child(userId).remove();  
});
```

Please note that I'm not really sure remove() would work since I work with Cloud Firestore primarily, but the idea should be the same.